# Removing items from a Dictionary using foreach

Tags: c#, dicionário

I am trying to test values of a SortedDictionary and removing some accordingly but I think the foreach doesn't accept the change in the Dictionary. Is there a better way of doing? Am I right about the kind of issue?

```
try{
    foreach (var elmt in buffer)
    {
        if (condition(elmt)
        {
             buffer.Remove(elmt.Key);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Logger.LogInformation("marker: " + e.Message)
}
```

The exception thrown is: "marker: **Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.**"

Answer (score 0):

A documentação diz: "Os enumeradores podem ser usados para ler os dados na coleção, mas não podem ser usados para modificar a coleção subjacente." No próprio [site](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-sorteddictionary-2-getenumerator).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).